# Sublinear time path existence

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, space-time-tradeoff

Consider a graph $G = (V,E)$ with $N$ edges. Consider two vertices $u_1, v_1 \in V$. We wish to find whether there exists a path of length $4$ between these two vertices or not. This is easy to do in $O(N)$ time by performing a BFS.

Clearly, there also exists a tradeoff between preprocessing space and answering time. I can use $N^2$ space by storing a bit for all possible vertex pairs to indicate whether there exists a path of length $4$ or not and answer each query in constant time. The other end of the spectrum is that BFS gives linear query time.

I am interested in using the least amount of space to answer the query for any pair of vertices $u_1$ and $v_1$. in sublinear time $N^{1-\epsilon}$. Any leads/papers/ideas appreciated!

Comment: There are $|V|^2$ vertex pairs, so are you assuming the number of edges $N = |V|$?

Comment: Yes. The input to the problem is the graph with $N$ edges which implies that size of domain of $V$ is also as large as $N$.

Comment: Is this question specific to the constant 4? Or is it some parameter k? (Which is assumed to be small?)

Comment: I am interested in all $k$ which are constants. The case of $k=2,3$ are easy to solve and known from existing work - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.05847.pdf (lemma 3). But the tradeoff is clearly not optimal since it is useless when $T = \Omega(N)$. $k=4$ is the first value where I cannot show that $S=N^{1+\epsilon}$ when answering time $T = N^{1-\epsilon}$.

Comment: No, a graph with $|V|$ nodes can have $|V|^2$ edges.

Comment: Can we use the original input graph for free, or does it also count towards the space bound in your setup?

Comment: The input graph also counts towards space. So in this setting, we can assume that we are interested in the regime where $S \geq O(N)$.

Comment: @smapers yes but I am counting the input as the number of edges. In general, the size of the graph is $|E| + |V|$ but assume that $|V| \leq N$ and the input to the problem is of size $N$.

Comment: Is the query going to be whether there exists (at least) one path of length (exactly) 4 that joins a pair of vertices? and would u-a-b-a-v count with node 'a'  re-used? (that is, are you limiting to *simple* paths?) Also, I agree with @smapers that your statement of space (a bit for each pair of vertices) just needs |V|^2 and not N^2